# Python Ray: Objects pinned in memory unable to evict

Tags: python, memory-management, genetic-algorithm, ray

I have created a custom NSGA2 algorithm and I'm using ray for my evaluator. I've noticed that the objects I retrieve from the ray task are being pinned and I've tried doing a couple things such as copying the returned objects and deleting the reference to the original, using garbage collector, or just deleting all references to ray objects after they're used but no luck.

When using ray memory I get this output many times (from each iteration of evaluations) :

```
Driver  f7dc3a80d7a578ceffffffffffffffffffffffff0100000001000000    47.9 MiB    PINNED_IN_MEMORY    /root/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py:wrapper:62 | Optimizer/components.py:evaluate_all:511 | Optimizer/components.py:evaluate_all:159 | Optimizer/components.py:iterate:134
```

The function is called in multiple areas:

```
class MapEvaluator:
      def __init__(...):
      def evaluate_all(...):
        ....
        results = []
        for i in range(len(chromosomes)):
            trial_idx = int(n_gen*population_size) + i
            offspring[i].trial_idx = trial_idx
            results.append(get_genes.remote(predictor, chromosomes[i], trial_idx, n_gen))

        chromosomes,evaluation,updates_pgScanCaseRate,cache = zip(*ray.get([result for result in results])) # this is line 511 from the above output
       .....
        del chromosomes,evaluation,updates_pgScanCaseRate,cache
       ....
      return offspring
```

Then it does some work and returns an object that references some of the objects retrieved from ray. I've tried making a copy of the object that needs to be returned but it doesn't seem to work.

2&3)

```
class NSGAII:
    def __init__(...):
    ....
    def iterate(...):
        ....
         offspring = self.evaluate_all(parents) # calls function below # line 134 from ray memory output
        
        offspring.extend(self.population)

    def evaluate_all(...):
         for parent in parents:
             offspring.extend(self.evaluator.evaluate_all(parent,n_gen,self.variator,self.breeding,self.population_size)) # line 159 from ray memory output
             #self.evaluator.evaluate_all calls the function from 1) from the evaluator class
```

The main problem is that I am running the GA sequentially (i.e. doing multiple runs one after the other)
E.g.

```
for problem in problems:
    run_optimization()
```

and the objects from the previous run are being pinned. I've read the documentation on memory management and they mention many ways objects can be pinned but not really any remedies for them.

Then I took a look at the source code and found the functions `ray.internal.internal_api.free` and `ray.internal.internal_api.global_gc` and tried both of them but they haven't worked

Answer (score 0):

`PINNED_IN_MEMORY` means that somewhere, the code is holding a pointer to shared memory. A common case where this can happen is when the object's value is a numpy array, which are accessed with zero copies. So most likely, the problem is this line:

```py
        chromosomes,evaluation,updates_pgScanCaseRate,cache = zip(*ray.get([result for result in results])) # this is line 511 from the above output
```

Although these variables are getting `del`'d later on, it's likely that some other variable (maybe the returned value `offspring`?) is holding onto a reference to one of these. Making a copy likely isn't helping because it's not a deep copy (copies the object pointers but not their values in shared memory).

You can free the object store memory by making a deep copy of the values returned by `ray.get`. But I would also consider keeping your current code if you don't need the additional object store memory for other objects; copying the values will add extra overhead

Comment: Yes, the offspring does have references to the chromosomes. I've tried creating a deep copy of the offspring to return and deleting the original but it hasn't worked. I've also tried creating a deepcopy of the chromosomes from the `ray.get` values but that didn't work either. I can't keep the code the way it is since it needs to perform the algorithm sequentially for many different problems at once. I can do ray shutdown and initialize it after each problem is finished but that seems like a hassle. Is there an explicit way to delete the objects that are being pinned?